# mod_rewrite's RewriteMap prg works just for first request

Tags: python, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a simple IP blacklist. Each request is evaluated against list of IPs and throws 403 if necessary. I decided to deal with it on Apache side with `mod_rewrite`, its `RewriteMap` and simple python script.

In `VirtualHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteMap banip prg:/path/to/script.py
    RewriteCond ${banip:%{REMOTE_ADDR}} !=OK
    RewriteRule ^/.* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

**script.py:**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

sys.stdout.write('OK\n')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Now the weird part. After restart of Apache, only first request returns `200` and every following request returns `403`. I'd expect all of them to return `200`. When I restart Apache, the same happens all over again.

**Rewrite log after restart of Apache:**

```
# Very first request
127.0.0.1 - (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /app_dev.php/
127.0.0.1 - (3) applying pattern '^/.*' to uri '/app_dev.php/'
127.0.0.1 - (5) map lookup OK: map=banip key=127.0.0.1 -> val=OK
127.0.0.1 - (4) RewriteCond: input='OK' pattern='!=OK' => not-matched
127.0.0.1 - (1) pass through /app_dev.php/

...

# Request after that
127.0.0.1 - (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /static/css/grid.css
127.0.0.1 - (3) applying pattern '^/.*' to uri '/static/css/grid.css'
127.0.0.1 - (5) map lookup OK: map=banip key=127.0.0.1 -> val=
127.0.0.1 - (4) RewriteCond: input='' pattern='!=OK' => matched
127.0.0.1 - (2) forcing responsecode 403 for /static/css/grid.css
```

On second refresh, it doesn't write *anything* to rewrite log, just throws `403` straight away.

When I try `RewriteCond OK !=OK` or `RewriteCond NOTOK !=OK`, it works perfect. Any idea why is this happening?

I'm on Xubuntu 11.10 with Apache 2.2.20 and Python 2.7.2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may want to take a close look at the [RewriteMap documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap).  In particular:

> This program is started once, when the Apache server is started, and
>   then communicates with the rewriting engine via its stdin and stdout
>   file-handles. For each map-function lookup it will receive the key to
>   lookup as a newline-terminated string on stdin. It then has to give
>   back the looked-up value as a newline-terminated string on stdout or
>   the four-character string ``NULL'' if it fails (i.e., there is no
>   corresponding value for the given key).

So, your program gets started once, receives a key from Apache, generates a response, and then *exits*.  As you can see from the documentation, *it will not get restarted*.

Your program should loop, reading a line of input, generating output, and then waiting for more input.  The linked documentation includes a very short example.